# Address normalization and matching in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, string-matching

I'm working with two big databases in PySpark that I have to join thorugh a combination of attributes: one of them are the addresses. I can't use geocoding, as data are too big to use some free geocoding tools so what I'm going to do is a join based on a similarity measure on the addresses (and equality between other attributes of the two datasets). My first question here is what you suggest, because now I'm focusing on the levenshtein distance (as can be used in spark SQL), and I don't know how performant can be in a context of more words. Always regarding the levenshtein, is it better to remove all the spaces between the words or keep them?

Secondly, I have to prepare the addresses for the join and I would like to normalize them (Street -> st., Avenue-> ave., before casefolding...), so I was wondering if you know an already available online list of these transformations that I could use (not only addresses written in english).

Comment: any leads/development on this @unter_983?

Comment: .@Fritz I went on using the Levenshtein distance and regarding the normalization I manually built a dictionary, that unfortunately is very short

Comment: i see. try and check this one out https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal. I'm looking on possibly using this for my address use case as well.